# VS angular2 changes do not update on browser

Tags: typescript, npm, angular

I'm starting on Angular2 and when I try to run the first time my project, it works. The problem is that i'm following the tutorial and any change at all is not showing on any browser when i run it!

This is my "app.component.ts":

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>Testing...</h1>'
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
}
```

this shows ok on any browser, but when i change to this:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>'
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
}
```

**it continues to show "Testing...". it suppose to show "Tour of Heroes". Why?**

All my other files are the same as the tutorial!

Ps.: I have installed "node and npm"!

[@PankajParkar mentioned a need of editting "System.config"]
This is what i have on my index.html as the same as in the tutorial on Angular2

```
<script>
    System.config({
      packages: {
        app: {
          format: 'register',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
      }
    });
    System.import('app/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
```

Comment: try refreshing cache of browser.. or do hard reload by `Ctrl + F5`

Comment: I did make a search before posting... F5, Ctrl+F5 and even disabling cache didn't work either!

When I change the port i'm using, it updates only one time and then continues to not updating...

Comment: delete cache or check whether your files compiled properly or not ?

Comment: there might be a chance that you are editing wrong file & cheking wrong file in console.. And are you doing `build` after a changes made in ts file... you need to re-run the project to make it working

Comment: There is  nothing wrong in your code, code seems  just fine, you should checkout your compiled js file once

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 comunity. Not using linux.

Comment: @PardeepJain How do I check if they are compiling prorpely? there are none js files on my project.

Comment: there is nothing to do with linux or VS 2015

Comment: what upto my knowledge only js files are going to run on browser not .ts file, and without js file how your code runs ? amazing

Comment: @PardeepJain here: http://s9.postimg.org/nap6gz45b/Angular_project.jpg
this is my project. you'll see that is the same as the tutorial on the Angular2 tutorial. No js files and it runs perfectly!

Comment: I sure, you are not re-running your project again..you have to do it to see the changes.. same issue I were facing few months before.. did you tried whatever I suggested?

Comment: @PankajParkar is it possible to run project using .ts only ?

Comment: exactly @Plinio try re-running your project once

Comment: @PardeepJain yes.. there we need to do some tweaks in `system.config` block.. I've not tried so not sure how to tweak it..

Comment: @PankajParkar
- well i don't have any console here, so that idk what you talking about...
- Yes I save all the files and then I press F5 on VS to run. Unless there is a "re-run" button when is not running to be pressed. Otherwise i admit i really dont know what to do.

Comment: @Plinio , pankaj just want to tell you that try once reStart your project, may be due to some reason you files may not saved properly thats y he ask you to rerun your project.

Answer (score 7):

This issue is so frustrating but this is how I made it work.

Hit F12 in your browser to bring up the Developer Tools. Disable the Cache as shown below

[image]

Secondly, I had to add this section just above  tag in web.config to disable cache

```
<location path="app">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache"/>
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Comment: Excellent: we'll just send instructions to every use of the site to hit F12 and disable the cache.. :( !!! 

On second thought, if that was actually required to get an updated application Angular would have not made it past the back-of-napkin stage.

Comment: @RickO'Shea Only if you had realized the issue (this answer specifically answers) is for development machines, did I said to go & ask everyone to hit F12?

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced same problem in vs. I have googled it but didn't get any solution. Then i clean my project solution and rebuild it. That figured out my problem. Please try it hope it will also solve your issue.

Comment: This actually worked for me, after trying a lot of other things.

Answer (score 1):

I see the same problem every time I start a new angular project in VS2017 version 15.1.
I have found that I can solve it by changing the "run target" (that setting next to the run button) from Default Browser to Chrome and then make sure that IIS Express is selected - i.e. you want it to start in a browser window when you press F5, not the default command window.